# how do i use FarsiLibrary.win.dll

Tags: c#

i have a windows application . i want to use FarsiLibrary to have a persian DateTime control in form.
but i can't use it, because i has error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FarsiLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

i just add the 'FarsiLibrary.Win.dll' to References and add this code:

```
using FarsiLibrary;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         private FarsiLibrary.Win.Controls.FADatePickerConverter faDatePickerConverter;

        // other code
     }
}
```

i use this link:

[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13664/Farsi-Library-Working-with-Dates-Calendars-and-Dat][1]

please help me.

Comment: Getting error while debugging? If not are you sure your reference is copied to output directory?

Comment: Any compiler **warnings**? If you properly added the reference, this error means the reference or one of its dependencies could not be found, which usually will be shown as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

it's solved:
i change 'Target framework' of solution Properties: from '**.NET Framework 3.5 client profile**' to '**.NET Framework 4**'
then it worked.

thank you all,